# Sharing rules on Opportunities

Tags: force.com, security, sharing

How do the Sharing rules on Accounts and other objects where Opps are  a child impact sharing rules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sharing is a cumulative setting, where all possible settings are combined into a single "answer" that determines what the user can do with a given record.

For example, if an account sharing rule grants "Edit" access to opportunities, while opportunity sharing only grants "Read" access, the user will still be able to edit the opportunity.

Opportunities are affected by the following settings:

- Ownership
- Opportunity Split
- Account Sharing Rules
- Account Teams
- Opportunity Sharing Rules
- Opportunity Teams
- Role Hierarchy
- Account Manual Sharing
- Opportunity Manual Sharing
- Territory Management
- Opportunity Ownership
- Child Access
- Organization Wide Defaults (OWD)

A record that is a child of opportunity that grants at least "Read" access to the record also grants "Read" access to the opportunity. It does not grant access to any other opportunities that are also linked to that opportunity through a common parent record.

These are the only settings that will allow access to the opportunity record, aside from profile and permission set settings that provide blanket access (View All Data/Modify All Data).

Sharing on other standard objects, such as campaigns, cases, contacts, and other records using standard relationships will not grant access to opportunities. Sharing on custom objects or custom relationships may grant access to opportunities through the implicit child rule (you can see the child object, so you can also see the parent object).

Comment: Does this "implicit child" rule work for r/w as well? Also how does the "implicit child" work from an OWD or Sharing rules?

Comment: There are implicit child rules and implicit parent rules. A child record grants read-only access to the parent implicitly. A parent can be configured to grant read-only or read-write access to its children through the OWD. This is probably better explained looking at the Help window.