# OpportunityShare record delete Exception

Tags: record-access-level

My scenario - I have a custom object 'A' and I have a lookup to custom object 'A' on Opportunity. The lookup is made mandatory on page layout of  Opportunity. OWDs of both 'A' and Opportunity is 'Private'.

'User1' and 'User2' belong to same profile and are at same role hierarchy level.

Step 1 - 'User1' creates a record for custom object 'A'. 
Step 2 - 'User2' creates a record for opportunity and associate it to record created above ( as there is a manadatory lookup to 'A' )

When I look at OpportunityShare object for the opportunity created above, I see an entry for 'User1' with rowCause = 'ImplicitChild' .

Please help me understand the reason behind this entry.

Comment: what does this have to do with the title - 'delete exception' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit sharing is used for some standard objects (Accounts, Contacts, Cases, Opportunities).

Depending on the scenario, either the parent object will get access to the child (for example an account will be able to see a child record added to it via **ImplicitParent** or

The child object (Opportunity in this case - it has a lookup to your object 'A') will be assigned an **ImplicitChild** to the 'A' object.

Here are the [docs](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunityshare.htm) for OpportunityShare

@sfdcfox also has a good answer on the subject [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18147/sharing-rules-on-opportunities)

Salesforce says:

> Access to a parent account—If you have access to an account’s child record, you have implicit Read Only access to that account.
>
> Access to child records—If you have access to a parent account, you have access to the associated child records. The account owner's role determines the level of access to child records.

[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_across_objects.htm&language=en_US) is the source for the Salesforce Quote above.

**EDIT** I noticed your title - 'OpportunityShare record delete Exception' - this may be due to the fact that this type of sharing rule is read only to everyone but the Salesforce system. The share is automatic and the only way to remove it would be to change the lookup or change the OWDs.

If the exception is related to something else, put the exception details on the question and I might be able to work it out.

Comment: Hi @CaspNZ, Thanks for your response. I forgot to mention this in my original post. Salesforce is adding entry in OpportunityShare with RowCause='ImplicitChild' and OpportunityAccessLevel='Edit' to 'User1'. This makes record created by 'User2' in Opportunity Editable by 'User1'. I was wondering why it should add 'Edit' access level ?